# Get real type of file that user want to upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

in my ASP.Net MVC 3 application I have uploading images logic. How can I find out is some file that user try to upload realy an image? I need to check it before uploading , on client side

Comment: Check *what*? You haven't provided a valid criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
Image.FromStream(stream)
```

it will throw an ArgumentException if it is not a valid image.

Comment: I need to check it before uploading , on client side

Comment: I see, so how about using the file extension?  Not perfect but in combination with a server check it would cover all cases, and cover most on the client side.  e.g. http://blog.navayan.com/jquery-validation-for-file-type-extension/